Integer factorizing the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{12}(q)=q^4-q^2+1$ evaluated at prime powers $q$
I am sure the answer to this question is 'no', but I should double check.
I know that there is no (known) polynomial-time algorithm for integer factorization. Does this change if you know that the integer $n$ in question is of the form $q^4-q^2+1$ for some prime power $q$, i.e., it is a cyclotomic polynomial? For example, every prime factor of this must be congruent to $1$ modulo $12$, which is one of those statements that feels useful but almost certainly isn't.
(This question can be applied to general cyclotomic polynomials, but I am specifically interested in the case of $\Phi_{12}(q)$ because it is the order of an element of the simple group ${}^3\!D_4(q)$. To find the normalizer of a $\Phi_{12}$-torus of this group I need to be able to take fourth roots in the unit group of the ring $\mathbb{Z}/\Phi_{12}(q)\mathbb{Z}$, i.e., break RSA. But my $n$ are special, and RSA is breakable for some $n$. My algorithm to do this is already pretty fast, but technically not Las Vegas polynomial time.)

How does $\Phi_{12}(q) = (q^2 + \sqrt{3} q + 1)(q^2 - \sqrt{3} q + 1)$ ever yield an integer factorization when $q$ is an integer?  BTW, $\Phi_{12}(3^{2n+1})$ happens to be prime for $n = 0, 1$ and $4$.

@RobertIsrael Sorry, you are right. What you are supposed to do is think of $3^{2n+1}$ as $q^2$, but that gives a factorization of $\Phi_6(3^{2n+1})$. I have removed it as it's of no general interest anyway and just confuses. You can do something with $\Phi_{24}(q)$ over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ for odd powers of $2$ to obtain a factorization of $\Phi_{12}(2^{2n+1})$, and I mixed it up.

If an expression has no algebraic factors , usually such a number is not easier to factor than a random number of the same magnitude. Only the quadratic sieve is more efficient if large powers are involved , but even then RSA reaches a limit relatively soon.

@Peter That's what I assumed. That's fine with me, it's just to make sure I don't say anything silly in a paper.
